# Large difference in reported free disk space

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hard-drive, ssd, disk-space

I have a strange discrepancy in the amount of free disk space that's being reported.

The finder says:

[image]

My iStat Menus says:

[image]

Which is the same as `df -h` reports:

```
remco@Prosperpine ~  $ df -h
Filesystem                          Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused   ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2                       148Gi  127Gi   21Gi    87% 33479179 5383643   86%   /
devfs                              187Ki  187Ki    0Bi   100%      646       0  100%   /dev
map -hosts                           0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0       0  100%   /net
map auto_home                        0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0       0  100%   /home
```

Why would such a large difference occur? I've checked the disk using the disk utility and it does not report having any issues.

Specs: Late 2011 MacBook Pro 17", non-Apple Intel 160GB SSD, OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the Storage section of About This Mac. You will probably see the missing 15GB listed there as "Backups". These are [Time Machine local snapshots](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4878), and Finder ignores them when calculating free disk space, because they get deleted automatically when your free disk space drops below 20%. In other words, they give up their space automatically as needed, so the number in Finder is the one you should pay attention to.

Comment: You're totally right, the numbers add up indeed. I didn't know that! Thanks a lot for your quick reply!

Comment: Should you want to delete them by yourself anyway, just do a "sudo tmutil disablelocal" and they'll be gone in a few minutes... :)

Comment: Page from Bjango confirming this: https://bjango.com/help/istatmenus4/disks/

Comment: With the latest macOS High Sierra you can no longer do `tmutil disablelocal`. However, you can thin out local snapshots yourself with `tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 10000000000`. See this post here that explores it: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309143/how-to-thin-your-local-time-machine-snapshots-on-macos-high-sierra/309144#309144