# APFS/High Sierra - tmutil deletelocalsnapshots will not delete snapshots - Error parsing argument

Tags: time-machine, apfs

This is kind of an addendum to [APFS/High Sierra - `tmutil deletelocalsnapshots` not deleting snapshots](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314038/apfs-high-sierra-tmutil-deletelocalsnapshots-not-deleting-snapshots) as I've discovered a new quirk in `tmutil`

My snapshots all have `am` or `pm` appended. I have no idea why & no-one else seems to have this from what research I've done.

This gives a new problem...

```
TetsMac:~ glee$ tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-07-26-93812 am (dataless)
TetsMac:~ glee$ tmutil deletelocalsnapshots 2018-07-26-93812
Error parsing argument 2018-07-26-93812
TetsMac:~ glee$ tmutil deletelocalsnapshots 2018-07-26-93812 am
Usage: tmutil deletelocalsnapshots <snapshot_date>
```

It can't find it if you leave the am/pm off & it thinks the format is wrong if you add it.

What else can be done to delete this errant snapshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered, after hints on the linked thread, that quotes will do it...

```
TetsMac:~ glee$ tmutil deletelocalsnapshots "2018-07-26-93812 am"
Deleted local snapshot '2018-07-26-93812 am'
TetsMac:~ glee$ tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
TetsMac:~ glee$
```

& it's finally gone.