# Cannot delete dataless localsnapshot in high sierra

Tags: macos, time-machine, high-sierra

I use macOS high sierra 10.13.6. I have problem with freezing standby resume. I read that dataless localsnapshot may be the cause. So I proceed to delete the dataless localsnapshot.

```
$ tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-10-10-170247 (dataless)
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-10-17-201830
```

then

```
$ sudo tmutil deletelocalsnapshots 2019-10-10-170247
Deleted local snapshot '2019-10-10-170247'
```

However, the dataless is not removed.

```
$ tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-10-10-170247 (dataless)
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-10-17-201830
```

How do I force delete the snapshot? I have tried booting into safe mode, but same result.

Update:

I am turning FileVault on. Encryption is in progress..

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314038/apfs-high-sierra-tmutil-deletelocalsnapshots-not-deleting-snapshots

Comment: @Tetsujin. I don't understand. Is it because am pm? I've tried adding am pm, bot no success.

Comment: No, that was a separate issue entirely. Basically, High Sierra & Time Machine are a washout. You periodically have to repair the disk, which will [might] fix it until next time. The only 'fix' is Mojave [which comes with its own set of issues, but not that one]

Comment: I'm stuck with high sierra (mbp late 2011). So I think I will revert to hfs+. @Tetsujin

Comment: Yup, that's the alternative & what I did until I could upgrade to Mojave [which i'm now stuck on, no Catalina for either of us ;) At least you can still use DiskWarrior on HFS+, which is often needed on the Sierras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After encryption has been finished, I can successfully delete the dataless local snapshot. I think local snapshots can't be modified while encryption is in progress.