# How can I free up storage on my MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, photos, storage, imovie

My MacBook Air is out of storage but I can't figure out how to free up storage. I've tried deleting videos and photos but this doesn't change anything. I've also tried deleting videos off iMovie but thus also doesn't help. I'm quite stuck, and would really appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Did you also empty the trash?

Comment: Also consider local snapshots to not release the space created by deleting those files.  Restart, or... https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309143/how-to-thin-your-local-time-machine-snapshots-on-macos-high-sierra

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in storage manager, Open spotlight (`cmd` + `space`) and type `sm` then enter. It will show you what's taking the most space and you can delete items there.

In High Sierra it looks like this...

[image]

Comment: Don’t forget that Spotlight learns and "sm" can have a different suggestion to Storage Manager.app, depending on what you’ve previously chosen.