# Rescan all disks in 'disk utility' on mac os mojave

Tags: macos, mojave, disk-utility

How do I "rescan all disks and volumes" in Disk Utility on mac os Mojave? My disk got full. Then I make 25GB empty space but according to Disk Utility, it is still full.

[image]

According to df, 25GB is available.

[image]

Restarting it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: It refreshes at relaunch, doesn't need a reboot. Did you empty your trash? If yes, check System Prefs > iCloud >  iCloud Drive Options… & see if Optimise Mac Storage is on.

Comment: Yes, I did empty my trash. I don't use iCloud.

Comment: OK, try thinning Time Machine snapshots - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309143/how-to-thin-your-local-time-machine-snapshots-on-macos-high-sierra

Comment: Today, disk utility is showing correct disk usage. It's buggy.

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks for the link. I tried the command: $ tmutil listlocalsnapshots / - it shows no snapshots.

Comment: OK, I'd have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space then