# Macbook pro 2017 intermittently cannot find start-up disk, especially when lid has been closed (Always starts when I reset NVRAM)

Tags: hard-drive, sleep-wake, startup

**Update: The laptop seems to always find the startup-disk when I book by. resetting the NVRAM**

When I close the lid on my macbook, often when it wakes up it will not find my start-up disk. **By this I mean that I get the flashing '?' folder icon.** Sometimes it will also take a few tries from shut-down to find it. However, apart from this there is no problem with it.

I have reset the NVRAM and PRAM and there is no problem with my start-up disk according to first-aid.

Please see below specs

[image]

What is the problem?

Is it maybe a loose connection between to the HDD - I have had that problem before. What I don't understand is why it should consistently perform fine but only have trouble on start-ups: this maybe makes me think that it's a software issue.

Thanks in advance,

Output of diskutil:

[image]

[image]

Diagnostics found no hardware issues (code: APD0000)

Comment: No issued when running diagnostics.

Comment: Per the HD giving you issues mainly on startup—another possibility is that there is an intermittent hardware connection issue that's temperature affected. If your machine is cool, it could mean more space between conductors in the intermittent break, which close when the system heats up—due to thermal expansion.

Comment: Have I exhausted the software avenues, would you all suggest I take a look under the hood at this point?

Comment: what is Konsole LOg telling to the crashes? APFS snapshots disabled? -> [APFS]: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309143/how-to-thin-your-local-time-machine-snapshots-on-macos-high-sierra"

Comment: Apple tells that they configure from 256 GB to 1TB SSD with this Model 2017, any more partitions. Where are the gapping GBs?

Comment: Hi @Flonn - can you please help me to understand what information I need to provide here - I am currently unclear. Thank you

Comment: There for sure is a high probably that the issue is hardware-driven.

Comment: @Floon If the Mac can't find its disk on boot there will be nothing in the logs about this...

Comment: @nohillside could there be a software reason behind it finding the startup disk when I reset the nvram? I'm not confident with computers - do you think I should take it to the shop?

Comment: Hard to say actually. If NVRAM tends to get corrupted it still might be hardware. But without a clear path to reproduce the problem a shop probably will just run some diagnostics and tell you "all looks good"...